# Texture resolution translate to SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

My problem is:
I've uploaded a File (a big Area with an orthophoto) in Forge. By translating to SVF, my orthophoto loses her quality (the resolution changes). I've seen that it's impossible to change that.
I found a solution to create an SVF without quality loss but on desktop (with 3dsMAX). How can I upload it on Forge.
I haven't found a way to unzip an svf folder in data-management and the unzip tools from the derivative want's to translate my file (what I don't want).
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Because you know it is working with 3ds Max, have you tried to translate the *.max format directly in Model Derivative (MD)? The desktop SVF exporter and the Model Derivative service translator should be the same for the max format.

Also, 3ds Max is available in Forge design automation. So if you needed to import from another format to produce the MAX format, you may be able to do that in Forge as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The basis file (I imported in 3DS) is a FBX and the translator also reduce the textures when I tried direct with the FBX. I've made a quick test with my max file and the texture doesn't come at the right place. I'll make a further test tomorrow.